# What is the best way to show multi-column grid using php + laravel + jquery + bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, grid

I am new to laravel. I want to show the DB returned data in a grid.
I am an old php user and I know that the easiest way is using "table" "tr" "td" to make a table.

Is there any better way to do it ?
by the mixture of laravel / jquery / bootstrap.

I know extjs can do it, but I don't want to write too much js.
Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: The best way is subjective, but I'd recommend using a library like datatables with jquery

Comment: check [**this**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jquery+grid)

Comment: Thanks Mark. It is MIT license, it seems good.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Nayjest/Grids](https://github.com/Nayjest/Grids) package for Laravel.